# Changing column names and values

Tags: r

Given the following data frame:

```
> df
     A1 A2 A2.1 A2.2 A3 B1 B2 B2.1 B2.2 B3
[1,]  0  0    0    0  0  0  0    0    0  0
[2,]  0  0    0    0  0  0  0    0    0  0
```

I seek to replace all "2.1" from the column names to " aa" and replace all values from those columns with the number 1. So that:

```
     A1 A2 A aa A2.2 A3 B1 B2 B aa B2.2 B3
[1,]  0  0    1    0  0  0  0    1    0  0
[2,]  0  0    1    0  0  0  0    1    0  0
```

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this with `grep` and `gsub`

```
x = c(0,3,5)
y = c(4,1,7)
z = c(1,2,3)
df = data.frame(x,y, z)
names(df) = c("A1","A2.1", "a2.1")

index <- grep("2.1",colnames(df))
df[, index] <- 1
colnames(df) <- gsub("2.1", "aa", colnames(df))

# > df
# A1 Aaa aaa
# 1  0   1   1
# 2  3   1   1
# 3  5   1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(sub(".*.", 1, .)), ends_with("2.1")) %>%
  setNames(sub("2.1", " aa", names(.)))
```

Which gives:

```
#  A1 A2 A aa A2.2 A3 B1 B2 B aa B2.2 B3
#1  0  0    1    0  0  0  0    1    0  0
#2  0  0    1    0  0  0  0    1    0  0
```

---

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A1 = c(0L, 0L), A2 = c(0L, 0L), A2.1 = c(0L, 0L
), A2.2 = c(0L, 0L), A3 = c(0L, 0L), B1 = c(0L, 0L), B2 = c(0L, 
0L), B2.1 = c(0L, 0L), B2.2 = c(0L, 0L), B3 = c(0L, 0L)), .Names = c("A1", 
"A2", "A2.1", "A2.2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B2.1", "B2.2", "B3"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: According to the OP and the desired output, only the "2.1" should be replaced by "aa" while the first letter of the column that is renamed is kept, like "A aa", "B aa" etc.

Comment: I really think it does. Please check again.

Comment: Here I copy-paste the column names according to the OP's desired output:  `A1 A2 A aa A2.2 A3 B1 B2 B aa B2.2 B3` The third entry, `A aa`, is the name of the first renamed column. Similarly, you can see that the desired name of the eighth column is `B aa`.

Comment: @RHertel You're right. I was looking on my cellphone and got mistaken with the column order. I edited accordingly. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
x = c(0,3,5)
y = c(4,1,7)
df = data.frame(x,y)
names(df) = c("A1","A2.1")

df 

#A1 A2.1
#1  0    4
#2  3    1
#3  5    7

df[,(grepl("2\\.1",names(df)))] <- 0
names(df)[which(grepl("2\\.1",names(df)))] <- "aa"

print(df)

  A1 aa
1  0  0
2  3  0
3  5  0
```

Comment: I think this is not a correct answer to the OP's problem: OP wants to retain all columns & the value has to be replaced by `1` and not `0`.

Comment: This is just a working example. It is trivial to use 1 instead of 0. Note that in the accepted answer, the column names are not as OP wanted

Comment: Thanks! Edited a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is only ever one letter at the start then simply do:

```
names(df)[substring(names(df),2,4) == "2.1"] <- "aa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion:

```
the_two_ones <- grepl("2.1", colnames(df))
the_letters <- sapply(colnames(df)[the_two_ones], function(x) gsub("2.1", "", x))
colnames(df)[the_two_ones] <- c(paste(the_letters, "aa"))
df[,the_two_ones] <- 1 
#> df
#  A1 A2 A aa A2.2 A3 B1 B2 B aa B2.2 B3
#1  0  0    1    0  0  0  0    1    0  0
#2  0  0    1    0  0  0  0    1    0  0
```